# ASP.NET - start a background task without returning any results and blocking the user

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, backgroundworker

I'm working on a project that when the user's registration is finished, there are some large file that has to be copied to some other locations and sometimes it takes around 10 min to copy everything.

I don't need the user to be notified and I don't need to show any progress, all I want to do is to show the user the that they have successfully registered and call a method on my web service to start a new background task to do all the time consuming tasks.

Any suggestions would help! Thanks.

**Edit:**

Thanks for suggesting the JavaScript method, but I don't want to use JavaScript since the user can have its JavaScript turned off on the browser.

I've already tried

```
 await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(() => copyFiles());
```

but the issue is that as I'm returning the view to the user, sometimes the server kills the thread earlier than it should and sometimes it never finishes its task (I could not figure out why)

Comment: sounds like a job for jquery

Comment: This is not a question, this is a statement of what you want your code to do. Please amend it so that you're telling us what you've done, and what you're having trouble with.  Stackoverflow is not a code writing service

Comment: @freefaller sorry for the misunderstanding, I edited my question

Comment: Tell us more about the files that are created and what copyFiles is doing.  Are you actually writing files to disc, or are you using a Stream?

Comment: @user3444160 I'm uploading the files from someother servers to SharePoint and on average we have 10 files around 100 MB each (~ 1GB/Account)

Comment: You could move the copy routines into a restful API, and then call it when you need to copy the files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few third party libraries related with background tasks in ASP.NET. Have a look at [this](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx) article by Scott Hanselman. It could be helpful for you.

Comment: Thanks I'll give them a try @volodymyr-zherebnyi

Answer (score 2):

You can use jQuery to call C# functions asynchronously. In these C# functions you can do your background work. You can even put these function in asmx file and make them [WebMethod]. See calling C# function with jQuery AJAX http://www.yogihosting.com/blog/calling-a-c-function-with-jquery-ajax/

Answer (score 2):

There is [a new method in .NET 4.5.2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn636893(v=vs.110).aspx), which allows you to do long-running background process in ASP.NET.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting that, I'm going to give that a try

Comment: unfortunately I won't be able to use this due to its limitation explained at the end of this blog:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/06/04/queuebackgroundworkitem-to-reliably-schedule-and-run-long-background-process-in-asp-net.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Well try using "jQuery.ajax" method in asynchronous mode. 
For your reference... http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: I think it is a bad idea for a 10 min process to run like this. It will rely on the session and the app pool remaining active. I'd have a windows service running and then this can look for new registrations and trigger the file copy.

Comment: Yes that's another great option. Use database flag to identify whether operation for that newly registered user is done or not. In this way you will separate both the activities.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your code with a task so it runs in a different thread.

```
// Use this method. Replace 'id' with the set of parameters you might need.
public void CopyFilesAsync(int id)
{
    System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(() => CopyFiles(id));
}

private void CopyFiles(int id)
{
    // your copy files code here
}
```